# PHP - Randomly empty post array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am running 2 apache EC2 servers behind a AWS Load balancer. Every couple thousand requests, I am seeing a randomly empty POST array.

The page is behind a login page, so I don't think it is a bot...

I am submitting a POST Ajax request via jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        data : $('#form').serialize(),
        url: "/page.php",
        complete: function(data, textStatus){ // do stuff here },
});
```

I don't know if the serialize function is failing somehow, or if there is something behind the scenes happening.

I know that a redirect can cause the POST data array to be empty, but there is no redirect happening as far as I can tell.

$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'] is set to 200.

This is causing an application error that I am handling and am notified of. I have not been able to replicate the error locally, so I can't look at the data sent by the browser.

Looking in the Apache error_log, I found

```
...proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 21096] (70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: [client (removed IP)] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade), referer: https://website.com/test.php
```

Any idea on how to track down the cause of this, to what the Apache error means?

Comment: that URL is behind a login page, so it can't be a bot ... I updated my question

Comment: You might consider using `success` versus `complete`. Really you can use both if you like.

Comment: Not sure if it would, but sometimes browser background prefetches can result in that kind of behaviour.  Would a HTTP GET trigger your ajax POST?

Comment: You may want to increase the logging too. For example, if PHP crashes or the PHP Spawn dies before the request is completed, you might get an empty POST Request. Do you see the incoming request in the Apache Logs?

Comment: Just because _the application_ requires a login that does not preclude anyone from submitting requests directly against the server. Are you certain that these are otherwise _valid_ requests from authenticated users?